# How Can I Make the Clickable Area be Applied to Whole Div, not Just Label?

Tags: html, css

I have been banging my head against the wall on this one for a while and can't seem to find how to do this. I have a card with two rows (card-body) classes. each row represents a radio button (input) with a corresponding label. When the user clicks the radio button I want the background to change colors. Right now that is working, but the background is only working for the label and not the whole div that contains the card row. I'm looking for a HTML/CSS-only answer, as I think it's probably something simple that I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

CSS

```
.card {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
.card-body {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 1.25rem;
}
.pick input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
  /* comment this line to see the radio buttons */
}

.pick label {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

.pick input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: blue;
}
.card {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
}
label {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body pick" for="i1">
    <input type="radio" name="g1" id="i1" value="you" data-target="r65">
    <label class="ben" for="i1" id="r1">you</label>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body pick" for="i2">
    <input type="radio" name="g1" id="i2" value="me" data-target="r65">
    <label class="ben" for="i2" id="r2">me</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j3mskfjv/11/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set your labels to display: block with width of 100%, like so:

```css
.card {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
.card-body {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
   
}
.pick input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
  /* comment this line to see the radio buttons */
}

.pick label {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

.pick input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: blue;
}
.card {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
}
.pick {
  display: flex;
}
label {
  display: block;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body pick" for="i1">
    <input type="radio" name="g1" id="i1" value="you" data-target="r65">
    <label class="ben" for="i1" id="r1">you</label>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body pick" for="i2">
    <input type="radio" name="g1" id="i2" value="me" data-target="r65">
    <label class="ben" for="i2" id="r2">me</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when I added it to my project, I realized there was some other css keeping it from expanding to the whole card-body. I've updated it on my original question, but do you know what I'm missing to get it to fill the top half of the card? height and width?

Comment: @kbjw17, try to remove `.card-body ` padding

Comment: @Core972 is correct.  You have a padding set to .card-body of 1.25rem, which is what's causing the issue. 

You can remove the padding from .card-body, and add it to the label rule I've added previously.  Please see my edited answer.  Thanks!